# Экспорт таблицы listView в Excel

Tags: c#

Помогите пожалуйста, как решить проблему экспорта. У меня есть определенное количество столбцов в listView их может быть меньше или больше и их название тоже может быть изменено. Так я нашел пример но он работает только если вписать название столбца которого нужно экспортировать . ws.Cells[1, 1] = "";
                ws.Cells[1, 2] = ""; --> это два пустых столбца, как их заполнить имя автоматически

```
private void excell_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(SaveFileDialog sfd=new SaveFileDialog() { Filter="Excel mon|*.xls", ValidateNames = true })
        {
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
                Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)app.ActiveSheet;
                app.Visible = false;
                ws.Cells[1, 1] = "";
                ws.Cells[1, 2] = "";
                int i = 2;
                foreach(ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
                {
                    ws.Cells[i, 1] = item.SubItems[0].Text;
                    ws.Cells[i, 2] = item.SubItems[1].Text;
                    i++;
                }
                wb.SaveAs(sfd.FileName, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                app.Quit();
                MessageBox.Show("Ваши данные успешно сохранены.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
    }
```

Код решения с ошибкой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нет выравнивания текста вообще
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Итого как должно быть после выравнивания текста слева на право
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: берешь тему которую я позначил как дублирующий вопрос и каждый item.SubItems конвертируешь в массив строк и добавляешь строку в ексель после чего вызываешь метод сейв. Почему интеропом лучше не пользоватся по ссылке так же есть обьяснение.

Comment: @Andrew мне просто нужен код, я сам мало изучал C# я думаю что вы скинули мне ни как не поможет

Comment: Я написал код просто потому что такое настроение хорошее. Вообще здесь код за тебя не пишут. Здесь помогают разобратся с ошибками, а пишешь ты сам. Если тебе нужно получить готовый код -- это на биржу фриланса, а не на SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если использовать ту библиотеку на которую я сослался (дубликат вопроса)

то код будет следующим:

```
private void excell_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(SaveFileDialog sfd=new SaveFileDialog() { Filter="Excel mon|*.xlsx", ValidateNames = true })
    {
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            SaveExel(sfd.FileName);
            MessageBox.Show("Ваши данные успешно сохранены.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}

public void SaveExel(string filepath)
{
    Excel xl = new Excel(); //создаем инстанс

    foreach(ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
    {
        var arr = item.SubItems.OfType<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>().Select(x => x.Text).ToArray();

        xl.AddRow(arr);
    }

    xl.FileSave(filepath);
}
```

код не проверял, могут быть некоторые ошибки в строке со звездочками

даный код не требует для работы установленного экселя а так же работает значительно быстрее. И не оставляет висящих инстансов экселя в бекграунде, как делает, скорее всего, твой код. (проверь таскменеджером и поубивай или перезапусти комп)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94486/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew---listview--excel).

Comment: @Andrew возможно что бы при экспортированном файле текст в Excel был слева на право ?

Comment: У тебя есть доступ к каждой из ячеек там. Ты можешь делать с любой ячейкой все что вздумается а потом сохранить. Просто бери и делай это перед вызовом метода сейв.

Comment: @Andrew можешь написать плз

Comment: Вообще здесь код за тебя не пишут. Здесь помогают разобратся с ошибками, а пишешь ты сам. Если тебе нужно получить готовый код -- это на биржу фриланса, а не на SO.

Comment: @Andrew за пару строчек какой смысл платить ? я просто спросил как это сделать, просто по подробнее бы. Почему у некрытых ЧСВ большое, надо быть немного добрее

Comment: А какой смысл делать за незнакомого человека пару строчек его работы если он и сам даже не попытался сделать эти пару строчек? Мне больше нужно? Не, я с темы удаляюсь. Здесь ПОМОГАЮТ разобратся с ошибками, а не пишут код вместо тебя.

Comment: @Andrew мм возможно просто я не понимаю твою библиотеку. А смысл сдесь тогда сидеть, почему русское сообщество настолько токсично. Ты понимаешь на англ. SO даже такого бы не писали, а просто написали код и объяснили что да как

Comment: Нет, на английском SO твой вопрос бы заминусили. Русское сообщество значительно лояльнее к такого рода вопросам. Не веришь -- пойди и проверь сам. Лично я когда начинал сидеть на английском SO и разбиратся с программированием был довольно быстро забанен из-за минусов к вопросам. :) Там бы просто тебе наставили минусов чисто за то что ты не хочешь даже пробовать писать код и ткнули бы в правила ресурса, которые ты, кстате, сейчас не соблюдаешь. И которые, кстате говоря, идентичные что для русского что для английского SO.

Comment: А еще, тебе рано разбиратся с программированием, если ты не можешь разобратся с 60тью строками кода той библиотеки которую ты "не понимаешь". Но давай будем говорить чесно, ты и не пытался понять что там написано в этих 60ти строках. И ты и не знаешь разницы между русским и английским контингентом SO, зато разглагольствуешь о токсичности. Возможно ты прав, и правильно было бы не словами говорить, а что бы русское сообщество стало жоще и просто минусило подобные вопросы как делает английское SO. Это эфективнее для создания вопросов хорошего качества вместо  упрашиваний "напиши код".

Comment: @Andrew ты не поверишь, на англ SO мне ни разу не минусовали вопросы, я прошу помочь мне разобраться

Comment: @Andrew сори я разобрался с формулами и куда че вписывать, подскажи только 1 строчку как выравнивания пжлст.

Comment: я не понимаю вопрос про выравнивание. Переформулируй его так что бы было понятно

Comment: Выравнивание всего текста слева на право

Comment: Мне вопрос все еще непонятен. Я не вижу того, что видишь ты. Я не знаю что это значит. Я не знаю что ты получаешь и что ты хочешь получить.

Comment: скрин добавлю выше

Comment: поищи как делать это через ClosedXML и проапдейть код Excel.cs соответственно к этому. Или поищи как принудительно ячейку позначить как текстовую и сделай это в коде Excel.cs. Так с ходу я на этот вопрос не отвечу. В даном случае все из-за того что ячейки с числами распознаются как числа. А они по дефолту в екселе располагаются с другим форматированием нежели текст. Соответственно к этому они и имеют выравнивание на правую сторону -- это дефолтные настройки самого экселя.

Comment: @Andrew окей с этим я разобрался, теперь вопрос в следующем как загрузить обратно этот Excel в listview

Comment: Сначала пробуй, а что не получится - создавай новый вопрос.