# Listview как произвести поиск в строке # или 2 и если они есть то

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

нужно найти в строке # или 2, и если есть то записать в строку столбца н/у, а если нету то "у"

```
            int summm = listView1.Columns.Count - 1;
            for (int itt = 0; itt < listView1.Items.Count; itt++)
           {

               string Totall2 = null;
                int tt = listView1.Columns.Count - 6;
                for (int i = 2; i < tt; i++)
                {
         Тут нужен код  ...    это не то --> Totall2 = Parse(listView1.Items[itt].SubItems[i].Text);
                }

                string sd = null;
                switch (Totall2)
                {
                    case "2":
                        sd = "н/у";
                        break;
                    case "#":
                        sd = "н/у";
                        break;
                    default:
                        sd = "у";
                        break;
              listView1.Items[itt].SubItems[summm-5].Text = sd.ToString();
            }
```

---

Итоговый результат должен быть такой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: все подобные трансформации с сумированием, заменами и прочей логикой делайте до того, как привжите данные к гриду.

Comment: @tym32167 нет, мне вот так нужно. Тут не суммирование, тут цикл на действие, мне нужен код на поиск # , 2 в строке. Тут замен никаких не будет, этот столбец пустой и ему не нужно попадать в бд, он должен быть визуальным

Comment: ну у вас же есть код на экспорт данных? Там же вы проходите по гриду и получаете с него данные, так? Какие проблемыскопипастить тот код и поменять под свои нужды?

Comment: @tym32167 причем тут экспорт данных вообще, это не grid это listview. Мне просто нужен поиск в строке и все, я знаю вы хотите как лучше но у меня вот такая задача

Comment: вот у вас экспорт [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/988893/179763), вот [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/988827/179763), оба  про listView, оба про проход по элементам, оба куда то выводят данные. Какие проблемы этот код скопипастить и переделать под себя?

Comment: @tym32167 это бред. Я вам говорю я беру данные из бд. В Excel мне не нужно выводить всегда в основном программа должна показывать все

Comment: Я понял, вы просто не видите параллели между "пробежать по данным и вывести в эксель" и "пробежать по данным и что то посчитать"